# Where can I find statistical information about the people who use Super User?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

I want to know whether there is a way of getting information such as age, sex, country of origin, etc. about *the users of Super User*. It would be a great tool to know what type of people are affected the most by Super User.

Comment: Note that all data is licensed under Creative Commons and requires you to both attribute the source, and to relicense it under the same terms when published.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [compose an SQL query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) that will search the most recent data dumps. Profile information you can get is:

- Id
- Reputation
- CreationDate
- DisplayName
- LastAccessDate
- WebsiteUrl
- Location
- AboutMe
- Views
- UpVotes
- DownVotes
- EmailHash
- Age

So from your list:

> <strike>age</strike>, sex, <strike>country of origin</strike>,

Gender is not an option on profiles, and we can't force users to give to us - but there is some information available.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. However, I'm a bit disappointed by the scope of the information available.

Comment: @the.midget there's only so much we can ask users for, sorry :/

Comment: Considering that when you signed up, you were not forced to divulge your age, sex, or country of origin... how do you think we would get this information if users _didn't_ provide it themselves?

Comment: @nhinkle was directed to me or..?

Comment: Simon no, it was directed at @the.midget.

Comment: @nhinkle I wouldn't have any problem disclosing that information, as long as it's kept anonymous. That way we could know -for example- how many users are female but not which of them are.

Comment: @the.midget but not everyone is comfortable with that. Everyone has a right to online anonymity. Why would we need to know how many males or females use the site? It makes no difference

Comment: @the.midget requiring that information would go against the core philosophy of Stack Exchange, and is not going to happen. We aren't Facebook.

Comment: Nor are we a marketing database.